# MySQL WHERE IN returns only the last row

Tags: mysql

I have a table of postcodes together with their Latitude and Longitude.
The user posts a list of Postcodes into a multiline textbox and a list is created and fed into `sql = "SELECT postcode, latitude,longitude FROM geocodes WHERE postcode IN (" & PCList & ")"`

PCList is in the format

```
 'AL7 2BQ ','B12 9BS ','B14 7QU ','B21 9SF ','B24 9PJ ','B27 7RR '
,'B33 0NG ','B42 1NN ','B63 4RH ','B64 5AB ','B65 0LG ','B70 9QL '
,'B73 5AB ','B79 7AG ','BH1 1EN ','BH1 4SX ','BH9 2HE ','BL1 8TH '
,'BL3 6JR ','BL4 9HF ','BL5 3YY ','BL8 2EQ ','BN2 5TB ','BN9 0AD' etc.
```

I only ever get the last postcode. I have tried MysqlDatareader, Datasets, The mySQL string returns the full list in workbench.

If I replace the sql with something "`SELECT postcode, latitude,longitude FROM geocodes WHERE postcode LIKE 'B65%'`" then I get a complete list of postcodes starting B65 in either the datareader or datasets but cannot get it to work with mySQL WHERE IN.

Here is the code:-

```
Protected Sub ShowLocsButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ShowLocsButton.Click
    Dim PCList As String = Replace(Me.PostcodeListTextBox.Text, vbCrLf, "','")
    PCList = "'" & PCList & "'"
    GetMarkers(PCList) 
End Sub

Protected Sub GetMarkers(ByVal PCList As String)
Dim PointsDs As New DataSet
    Dim PointsDa As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim ConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnString").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(ConnString)
    command.Connection = conn
    If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        conn.Open()
    End If
    sql = "SELECT postcode, latitude,longitude FROM geocodes WHERE postcode IN (" & PCList & ")"
    command.CommandText = sql
    PointsDR = command.ExecuteReader()
    'Dim myrow As Integer = 0
    Me.VRPMap.Layers.Clear()
    'MsgBox(PointsDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count)
    While PointsDR.Read
        Dim myPostcode As String = PointsDR.GetString(0)
        Dim myLatitude As String = PointsDR.GetValue(1)
        Dim myLongitude As String = PointsDR.GetValue(2)
    End While
    conn.Close()
```

end sub

Comment: This problem is caused by code that we can't see.

Comment: what is `& PCList & `

Comment: Is the last space in every post code indented?

Comment: I have just noted the trailing space in the postcode strings, but this is not affecting  mySQL returning the full list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its was the training space, replaced vblf with vbcrlf in my string creation, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = "SELECT postcode, latitude,longitude FROM geocodes WHERE postcode IN (" % PCList % ")"
```

Comment: No that doesn't work, syntax error at %. I think it is down to the trailing space in each post, if I remove them it works, so my code Dim PCList As String = Replace(Me.PostcodeListTextBox.Text, vbLf, "','")
    PCList = "'" & PCList & "'" is not returning a proper value without the trailing space.